# FTP Issues Downloading Large Directory

Tags: php, linux, firefox, ftp, ftp-client

When I use FireFTP (or other FTP clients for that matter) to download large directories the download gets messed up.  It seems to work unendingly and show a nearly completed percentage. Then it will change and show a status percentage much farther from completion.  So usually what I have to do with large directories is ssh into the host and zip or tar the file and then download the tarred file.  Is there a reason and/or solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the client to use passive mode. Then try again.

Comment: it is in passive mode